# Python CSV read quoted field with embedded separator

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse KiCad schematics. Example text is:

```
F 0 "J1" H 10100 700 50  0000 R CNN
F 1 "1/8\" SJ1-3544" H 10350 800 50  0000 R CNN
F 2 "dish-components:CUI_SJ1-3544" H 10050 1200 50  0001 C CNN
F 3 "https://www.cui.com/product/resource/sj1-354x.pdf" H 10050 1200 50  0001 C CNN
F 4 "CP1-3544-ND" H 10050 1200 50  0001 C CNN "DigiKey"
```

I'm trying to parse this with

```
csv.reader(lines, delimiter=" ", doublequote=False, escapechar='\\', quotechar='"')
```

For line 1, this returns

```
['F', '1', '1/8', 'SJ1-3544"', 'H', '10350', '800', '50', '', '0000', 'R', 'CNN']
```

I'm hoping to receive this:

```
['F', '1', '1/8" SJ1-3544', 'H', '10350', '800', '50', '', '0000', 'R', 'CNN']
```

Specifically, the second field breaks up into two: `1/8` and `SJ1-3544"` instead of `1/8" SJ1-3544`. Note the double-quote at the end of `SJ1-3544"`.

What am I missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The `escapechar` option lets you specify an escape character (backslash in your case) for embedded quotes and delimiters.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar

Comment: Thank you, @IronMan. I have `escapechar='\\'` in my call. Did I spell it wrong?